# How was $f(x) = -2x-1$ found in this system?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

Find the linear equations $f$ such that $(f\circ f)(x) = 4x+1$

If $f$ is linear, then it has the form $f(x) = ax+b$.

Since $f(f(x)) = a(ax+b)+b=a^2x+ab+b=4x+1$, we get the system

$$a^2 = 4$$
$$ab+b = 1$$

The solutions I got are $a=2$ and $b = \frac{1}{3}$.

So one of these linear functions is $f(x) = 2x+\frac{1}{3}$

The book says that the other one is $f(x) = -2x-1$, but, **how did it get it**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system of equations
$$
a^2=4\\
ab+b=1
$$

has two solutions;  the first equation says $a=\pm 2$.  Thus the second equation takes two forms:

$$
2b+b=1\Rightarrow b=\frac{1}{3}
$$
and

$$
-2b+b=1\Rightarrow b=-1
$$